# which wallet is usable with ganache test-rpc?

Tags: truffle, wallets, testrpc, myetherwallet, ganache

I tried metamask, but unable to send ether between accounts because metamask is trying to estimate gas and gets stuck :(
myetherwallet doesn't save my seed so I need to enter it all the time

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [source code of MyEtherWallet](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases) release and add a custom node to your testrpc instance.  [image]

You will then be able to interact with your testrpc wallet addresses to view balance and send transactions.